# Increase the Tap area of the Android application

Tags: android, sqlite, opengl-es

I am Working on an android application. Which is same as globe. I want to set the tap on the points(cities) which are mention on the globe . i also do have the database(Lat,Long and Other data) of the points which are mention on the globe. I want the functionality that when i tap on the globe like i want to search the New york city it gets the lat,long of the New york city and gives me the all details from the database . and the problem is i set the database but when i tap on the globe it don't give me the details so i want to increase the tap area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is VIEW object this may help :

```
public static void increaseClickArea(View parent, View child) {
    // increase the click area with delegateArea, can be used in + create
    // icon
    final View chicld = child;
    parent.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Post in the parents message queue to make sure the
            // parent
            // lays out its children before we call getHitRect()
            Rect delegateArea = new Rect();
            View delegate = chicld;
            delegate.getHitRect(delegateArea);
            delegateArea.top -= 600;
            delegateArea.bottom += 600;
            delegateArea.left -= 600;
            delegateArea.right += 600;
            TouchDelegate expandedArea = new TouchDelegate(delegateArea,
                    delegate);
            // give the delegate to an ancestor of the view we're
            // delegating the
            // area to
            if (View.class.isInstance(delegate.getParent())) {
                ((View) delegate.getParent())
                        .setTouchDelegate(expandedArea);
            }
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: This application is same as globe. Let me check if it works .